# Why is the output is 0?? (PHP in Joomla)

Tags: php, joomla

we are facing this problem when using PHP in Joomla.. We wanted the output to be 3.

In the HTML we declare:

```
var address;
address = '3';
```

and put the below code in the form:

```
<td><input type="text" id ="amount1.2" name="amount" value="<?php $address = JRequest::getVar('address');?>"/>
```

In the process/server page, we put the following code:

```
$address = JRequest::getVar('address', 'default value goes here', 'post','variable type');
```

But the output is 0.

Comment: "var address;" That's no HTML...

Comment: The output of what? Also, getVar should take something from $_GET or $_POST array (IIRC, but anyway it doesn't magically retrieves variables from anywhere), no from javascript or whatever is where you wrote 'address'

Comment: -1 http://www.emilvikstrom.se/whyidownvote.html (What is your question? Do you know the language?)

Answer (score 1):

First, your starting code block is javascript, not HTML.

Second, in the other code examples you are only assigning some value to the PHP variable `$address`. If you want to have it appear in the HTML, you need to `print` or `echo` the variable:

```
<td><input type="text" id ="amount1.2" name="amount" value="<?php echo JRequest::getVar('address'); ?>"/>
```